How to hash using md5 oracle blob in c# using linq2db?
I want to hash blob data of oracle table. I saw two options : doing it in database using DBMS_CRYPTO or writing a processor which will go throw all blobs, gets the streams and hashes them using md5. Hash itself will go to another table which has foreign key to the table where blob data is stored as content of file. Some files are more than 100mb. Theoretically I can process them in small batches, but not sure about memory efficiency even if I handle only batch size 10.
P.s there are almost 20k blob data needs to be hashed

Which SQL do you expect? Post how do you plan to decrypt and encrypt via SQL query.

What is your actual question? What do you need help with?
